# Titanium healtkit module

Tags: module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, healthkit

I trying to use the Titanium Healthkit module in Appcelerator Labs and I am getting an error. I am using Ti SDK 5.2.0

```
HKHealthStore: failed to determine authorization status: Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=4 "Missing com.apple.developer.healthkit entitlement."
```

I have been reading through the posts on the old forum, and this seems to be a common error.  https://archive.appcelerator.com/topic/1596/apple-healthkit-integration/11

Is there any new or updated info? I am reluctant to patch the SDK, because I don't know if it is still valid or what it will do.

Answer (score 0):

On the Labs page it says:

> You will also need to add HealthKit to the app’s list of entitlements. See the Entitlements.plist file in the example folder.

Did you add that to your project?

Comment: I added Entitlements.plist to the root, UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities healthkit  added the tiapp.xml and I also put the mobileprovision in the root.

Comment: I opened the app in X-code,  went to the capabilities section and noticed a red exclamation point next to "Add the Healthkit entitlement to your app ID"and "link HealthKit.framework".  I clicked "Fix issues", and they were fixed.

Comment: Just be aware that when you clean your Titanium project you will have to redo that.